# QFileSystemWatcher does not detect the change of files

Tags: pyqt5

I'm trying to implement a small script, which automates a task by detecting a change either in a file or in a specific directory, but for some reason the methods that I defined to detect those changes do not detect anything.

This is my code:

```
import sys
import signal
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject

import getopt

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,signal.SIG_DFL)

class Watcher(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)

        # assign directory path
        self.directorywatcher = []
        # assign path of some single file
        self.filewatcher = []
        # get console arguments
        self.get_Argv()
        self.call_watchers()

    def get_Argv(self):

        arguments = sys.argv[1:]
        options = "d:f:"

        try:
            arguments,values = getopt.getopt(arguments,options)

            for argument,value in arguments:
                if argument in ("-d","--directory"):
                    self.directorywatcher.append(value)
                elif argument in ("-f","--file"):
                    self.filewatcher.append(value)
        except:
            print("invalid arguments")

        # Define listener function for files in set directories

    def call_watchers(self):
        
        if self.filewatcher != []:
            self.single_file_change()
        elif self.directorywatcher != []:
            self.directory_files_changed()

    def directory_files_changed(self):
        directory = QtCore.QFileSystemWatcher(self.directorywatcher)
        directory.directoryChanged.connect(lambda:self.modifyDirectory())


        # Define listening function for selected single files

    def single_file_change(self):

        file = QtCore.QFileSystemWatcher(self.filewatcher)
        file.fileChanged.connect(self.modifyfile)

        # Create file modification function in views\
    def modifyDirectory(self):
        print("change directory")

        # Create single qrc file modification function

    def modifyfile(self):
        print("modified file")


app = QtCore.QCoreApplication([])
w = Watcher()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It seems that the problem appears because I try to call QFileSystemWacher from a method of a class

Comment: The QFileSystemWatcher instances you're creating are just local variables, they get garbage collected as soon as the function in which they're created returns. Make them instance attributes: `self.directory = QtCore.QFileSystemWatcher(self.directoriesWacher)`. Also, please avoid adding code comments in a language different than English: if they are important for the question, then translate them, otherwise remove them, as they're just distracting and useless to anybody else. It's also good practice (and politeness) to also use English for object names like variables and functions.